# 0x for 8 bit, what is used for 7 bit?

Tags: hexadecimal

I am writing some technical documentation and describing a format for I2c 7 bit addressing mode. This is also related to ASCII 7 bit encoding, but that is a side note.

I2c uses 7 bits (or 10 bits not discussed here) to address a slave device. Following the 7 bits address is another bit to tell the slave to read or write.

Eight bits are transmitted when sending an address, but in reality, it is 7 bits plus a direction bit (R/w#).

My question: **if 0x is used to describe a base 16, hexadecimal, eight bit byte, what is used to describe a base 15, (uh quindecimal?) seven bit byte?** Maybe the word *byte* is also incorrect here.

I know 0x is also used to describe 16 bit words, but logically, they are really two 8 bit bytes together, so 0x feels OK.

Note: I got the word quindecimal from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171227154944/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/60405.html).

Mark.

Comment: Bits are binary. 0x is hex, which is *not* binary. It just maps nicely because it's a power of two.

Comment: Oh yeah, and a single hex digit maps to 4 bits, not 8. So I totally don't get what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You're confusing the number of bits with radix (aka base).  *"I am writing some technical documentation..."* -- Then you need to use proper punctuation for *"7 bit encoding"*.  It's not "7 encoding" nor "bit encoding", but "7-bit encoding" (i.e. the "7" and "bit" go together, so it's hyphenated).

Comment: You should be using hexdecmial notation, and making it clear the values are 7-bit encoding, to make your documentation easier to read.  Hexadecimal exists for us, humans, a computer doesn't care.  The computer is going to store the value within a register of a specific size even if the 7-bit data structure being stored only stores 7-bit

Answer (score 2):

You do not have it quite right. We use `0x` to indicate numbers expressed in hexadecimal, base 16. It is perfectly fine to use `0x` before numbers of any length, so long as you are expressing them in base 16.

If you see "0x1", it's just like seeing 1. It could be a single one bit. It could be a byte. It could be arbitrary length. No specific length is implied by the "0x".

Answer (score 2):

Base15 doesn't mean 7-bit byte. The concepts have no relation whatsoever...

A 7-bit byte is just that. A byte in which the most significant bit isn't used.
There is nothing wrong in using hexadecimal notation with 0x prefix to display values stored in such 7-bit bytes, as long as you make it clear that only 7 bits are valid. (In other words: 0x0* to 0x7*, the 0x8* and higher numbers aren't used.)

To my knowledge there isn't any special notation for this.
I have been programming for more than 30 years and back in the day these 7-bit systems where much more common than they are today. If there was a special notation for this I would have encountered it at some point but I never did.